# .NET Reflection, Launch WPF app. Resources Exception

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, vb.net, system.reflection

I'm trying to call an application using reflection in .NET.

The code is:

```
      Dim Assy As Assembly = Assembly.LoadFile("E:\WpfDemo.exe")
      Assy.EntryPoint.Invoke(Nothing, Nothing)
```

It works for almost everything (Win Forms, Console...) except WPF projects.

The WpfDemo.exe is a simple Empty WPF project compiled. It has just a Window.

When i'm trying to launch a WPF app i get:

```
TargetInvocationException
Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
   at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[]     arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(Object     obj, Object[] parameters, Object[] arguments)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj,     BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo     culture)
   at W8K2.ICU.Main(String[] args)
```

And the inner exception:

```
IOException
Cannot locate resource 'mainwindow.xaml'.
   at MS.Internal.AppModel.ResourcePart.GetStreamCore(FileMode mode,     FileAccess access)
...
```

It looks like WPF app is looking for the resources in the wrong place when it's being launched by reflection. When I execute the WpfDemo alone it works perfectly.

Thank you!

Comment: If I was to guess, the WPF app looks for the resource without specifying the assembly explicitly, meaning it would fall back on the executing assembly, which works when the WPF exe is executed standalone but in your scenario your bootstrapper becomes the executing assembly, and your bootstrap does not have such a resource.

Comment: It's the same reason that ILMerge doesn't work with WPF applications.